# Python is saying that a variable has not been assigned when it has

Tags: python

```
import random
import time
name=input("Welcome to the game what is your name")
print(("This is a numbers game"),(name),("you will be playing against the computer."))
print("The idea of the game is to get closer to 21 to the computer without going over 21"),
ready="N"
ready=input("Are you ready to play the game yet?").lower
if ready=="yes" or ready=="y":
    score=0
    while (score)<21 and (ready == "Y" or ready == "Yes" or ready =="YES" or ready == "yes" or ready =="y"):
        player1=random.randint(1,21)
        score=(score+player1)
        time.sleep(3)
        print(("you have scored"),(score))
        if score <21:
            ready=input("Do you want to add more to your score?")
if score>21: *THE PROBLEMS ON THIS LINE HERE*
    print("Sorry Over 21 , The Computer Wins!")
else:
    print("ok Well done let us see what the computer can do with their turn")
    computerscore=0
    while(computerscore)<21 and (computerscore)<(score):
        computer=random.randint(1,21)
        computerscore=(computerscore+computer)
        time.sleep(3)
        print(("The computer has scored"),(computerscore))
        if (computerscore)<=21 and (computerscore)>(score):
            print("Sorry the computer wins")
        else:
            print("You win well done")
        break
```

I get an error that says if score>21:
NameError: name 'score' is not defined

but I have put    score=0 so isn't that defining it?

Comment: score is only defined within the `if ready...` scope. it needs to be defined beforehand

Comment: you assigned the variable score after you are ready i.e. the first if. for the second if, score is not defined. :)

Comment: @Adam Does the problem only appear when you enter "n"...?

Comment: @deceze sorry, wrong terminology ;)

Comment: the problem is ```if score>21``` which you should be after ```if ready...```

Comment: `ready` will never be `'yes'`or `'y'`, because you never call `lower`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you are inputting the value `yes` correctly, the issue may be because of the line -

```
ready=input("Are you ready to play the game yet?").lower
```

You are assigning the reference to the `lower` function in `ready` , instead you should call `lower()` and assign the return value in `ready` . Example -

```
ready=input("Are you ready to play the game yet?").lower()
```

---

Also, if you want your code to work, when you do not input `ready` as `yes` , you should set `score=0` , before the `if` condition - `if ready=="yes" or ready=="y":`

Answer (score 1):

The variable `score` is declared inside an `if` block.

Suppose `ready` is different from `"yes"` and `"y"`, then the line `score=0` is never reached.

So `if score>21:` raises an error.

You have to set a default value like `score = 0` before entering to the first `if` condition.

Moreover, you made a typo:

```
ready=input("Are you ready to play the game yet?").lower
```

You should call the function using `.lower()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to intend the `if score>21:` line and everything that follows so that part of the code is included within the upper if coverage.

```
import random
import time
name=input("Wecome to the game what is your name")
print(("This is a numbers game"),(name),("you will be playing against the computer."))
print("The idea of the game is to get closer to 21 to the computer without going over 21"),
ready="N"
ready=input("Are you ready to play the game yet?").lower
if ready=="yes" or ready=="y":
    score=0
    while (score)<21 and (ready == "Y" or ready == "Yes" or ready =="YES" or ready == "yes" or ready =="y"):
        player1=random.randint(1,21)
        score=(score+player1)
        time.sleep(3)
        print(("you have scored"),(score))
        if score <21:
            ready=input("Do you want to add more to your score?")
    if score>21: *THE PROBLEMS ON THIS LINE HERE*
        print("Sorry Over 21 , The Computer Wins!")
    else:
        print("ok Well done let us see what the computer can do with their turn")
        #same with the rest
```

Answer (score 0):

On a different note, this script might be flawed because there is a lot of possibility that someone will key in something different. You may want to include in the line:

```
ready=input("Are you ready to play the game yet? Type 'Y' for Yes").lower()
```

some more text about what you want the player to specifically put in.

However, as mentioned above, the main point is `lower()`, this contributes to the error.